# Is this the right way of doing it?

Tags: c#

I just wrote a mutable `Point` class that tries to follow [these guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx) while using the new features of C# 6.

```
public class Point
    {
        public int X, Y;
        public static Point Zero => new Point(0, 0);
        public static Point Up => new Point(0, -1);
        public static Point Down => new Point(0, 1);
        public static Point Left => new Point(-1, 0);
        public static Point Right => new Point(1, 0);

        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public static Point operator +(Point a, Point b) => new Point(a.X + b.X, a.Y + b.Y);

        public static Point operator -(Point a) => new Point(-a.X, -a.Y);

        public static Point operator -(Point a, Point b) => a + -b;

        public override bool Equals(object o) => Equals(o as Point);

        public bool Equals(Point p) => (X == p?.X) && (Y == p?.Y);

        public override int GetHashCode() => X ^ Y;

        public static implicit operator string(Point a) => $"Point({a.X}, {a.Y})";

        public override string ToString() => this;
    }
```

This bit of code evaluates to false

```
Point.Zero == Point.Zero
```

I am fully aware of why it does so but the question is should it evaluate to false? It just doesn't quite look right to me. Does my `Point` class correctly follow the guidelines?

edit: I simply don't know whether or not it should evaluate to false. I want to know what people think it should evaluate to.

edit 2: **How to tell whether or not a class should be mutable?**

Comment: You should not override GetHashCode and Equals in mutable classes.  If you store two equivalent values using a hash (like Dictionary or HashSet) and then mutate one, you the dictionary won't be able to find it because you just changed its hash (which puts it in a different storage bucket).

Comment: Are you sure that you want `Point.Zero = new Point(42, 17);` to work?

Comment: @BryceWagner how am I gonna check the equality of 2 points if I don't override `Equals` then?

Comment: @nvoigt Right... But you should tell him that he has to use `readonly`... and then add a property to make the `Point` totally readonly (so that you can't do `Point.Zero.X = 5`)

Comment: Doesn't `Point Zero => new Point(0, 0);` *always* return a `new Point`?

Comment: @crashmstr Mmmh right... But at least he solves the problem of `Point.Zero.X = 5`

Comment: @nvoigt you mean `==` instead of `=` right?

Comment: Changing the subject of the discussion a little, are you sure you really want a mutable `Point` in the first place?

Comment: @foxneSs You need to make the class immutable or provide some other method besides the default "Equals" to do equality comparisons.

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes, I use `Point` to store a particle's coordinates for example.

Comment: But the points aren't moving, the particles are.

Comment: @JamesThorpe but if a particle moves then I have to change that particle's coodinates and `Point` provides a more convenient way of doing that instead of just using 2 int variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `==` does not automatically call equals unless it is overridden.  It will call the `==` operator on its base classes, which in your case is just `object`.  The `==` operator on `object` uses reference equality, so you are asking if two `Point` *references* are equal, which in your case they are not, since your static methods return a *new* instance each time.

So given that:

> should it evaluate to false?

Based on how you've written the class, yes, it should.  If you *don't* want it to evaluate to false, then you need to change something.

> Does my Point class correctly follow the guidelines?

You haven't overridden `==`, so it will use the default behavior, which follows the guideline.  If you make `Point` *immutable*, then overriding `==` would be appropriate.

If you *don't* want `Point.Zero == Point.Zero` to return false, here are some ways to do that:

- Use `Equals` instead of `==` to imply value equality
- Change the static methods to return the same instance each time. Have one instance that represents `Zero`, `Up,` etc. and return them instead of creating new instances.
- Change `Point` to be a `struct` which will use value equality instead of reference equality by default.

Note that if you change `Point` to be a `struct` then you should also make it immutable.  Mutable structs [can be challenging to work with](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/) since they get copied when passed around. So if you change a property value you are changing the property value of a *copy* of the struct.

Comment: I already said that I'm fully aware of why that happens. I just want to know people's opinions of whether or not I've written that class the right way.

Comment: So are you really just asking "should it evaluate to false?"  Well, you wrote the class, so that's up to you.  If you're wanting review comments for "working" code then go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: "Based on how you've written the class, yes, it should. If you don't want it to evaluate to false, then you need to change something." This is exactly what I'm talking about. I simply don't know whether or not it should evaluate to false. I want to know what people think it should evaluate to.

Comment: I've decided to make `Point` immutable. How do I overload `==`? Like this `public static bool operator ==(Point a, Point b) => a.Equals(b);`?

Comment: Basically, yes.  Not sure if you can overload operators like that but you get the idea.

Comment: However, I would document that the behavior of `==` is different than for other reference types.  It's not necessarily a bad thing, but if you are going to be different than you need to let consumers know.

Comment: @foxneSs I answered below how to override the == operators. You can add the null checks, or adapt to reuse the Equals method you've already written.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will clarify. This code:

```
 public static Point Zero => new Point(0, 0);
```

Is the equivalent of this code:

```
 public static Point Zero
 {
     get { return new Point(0, 0); }
 }
```

It is evident here that a new instance of Point is being created each time Point.Zero is called. The == operator performs a reference check by default, and since those are two separate instance of Point, the comparison fails.

You could override the == operator similar to how you've overriden the +,- operators:

```
public static bool operator ==(Point a, Point b) => a.X == b.X && a.Y == b.Y;

public static bool operator !=(Point a, Point b) => a.X != b.X || a.Y != b.Y;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `Zero` property is creating a new point every time you access it. SO when you compare these:

```
Point.Zero == Point.Zero
```

You are in fact comparing two completely different instances! And the `==` compares only the address in memory of the 2 points, so that's why it is false.

Now that's out of the way, let's see how we can make it *true*! There are numerous methods actually.

1. Use the `Equals` method instead of the `==` operator
2. Overload the `==` operator in the class
3. Make `Point` a struct. (Note: this will require some changes to the existing operator overloads as a struct is a value type)
4. Actually, if you want it to return true, why not just write 1 == 1? XD

I see that you want some advice from us, don't you? Here are some:

1. C'mon, who wants a mutable class?
2. If you want it to be mutable, don't override `HashCode`
3. Your "constants" are declared really badly. I'm not even sure if they are supposed to be constants. It should be like this, ya know:

   private static Point zero = new Point(0, 0);
   public static Point Zero {
       get {return zero;}
   }

or just simply:

```
public static readonly Point Zero = new Point(0, 0);
```

4. I think a struct would be more appropriate for a `Point`. It's a "structure" after all. Even `System.Windows.Forms.Point` is a struct.

Comment: Good advice. I'm definitely taking that into account.

Comment: Some refutes:  1) There's nothing wrong with mutable classes, 2) If you override `Equals` you should also override `GetHashCode`.  Mutable types aren;t good candidates for hash keys, but there's nothing wrong with implementing `GetHashCode` to be consistent with `Equals`  4) Why is `Point` intrinsically a struct?  What makes it a struct versus a class?  Just because Microsoft's `Point` type is a struct doesn't necessarily mean that _every_ `Point` class should be.